# Can I use a ShareThis/AddThis Button if my site's navigation relies on Hash tags in the url?

Tags: hashcode, sharethis

I want to embed a ShareThis/AddThis button on my site but the site's navigation relies on Hash tags in the url. Each page is assigned a unique hash value (ie, http://domain.com/index.php#products). Changing the navigation/page design isn't an option. Will these service preserve the hash value (both embed JS on the page)? If they don't, what are some alternative solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace the # with %23 (the URL encoded version of #) and you'll be fine. ;) I like to use the "remote" version of addthis : `http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?url=your_url_here%23hash_tag_here`

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to test this with their JS embed buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript button's share-url can be set manually for both services.

AddThis docs: http://www.addthis.com/help/sharing-api

Excerpt from ShareThis doc's (http://blog.sharethis.com/faq/developers-faq/sharethis-api-examples/)

> Define Your Sharable Objects:
>
> Using the ShareThis API, it is easy to
>   define the sharable objects. As an
>   example, a website that sells products
>   is able to define such detail as
>   title, description, product image.
>   When an item is shared, the recipient
>   will be able to see all the details
>   defined. Here is an example of code
>   that could be used:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    SHARETHIS.addEntry({
        title:'Best Digital Camera',
        summary:'This digital camera has all the features one would ever need!',
        url:'http://mystore.com/digitalcamera',
        icon: 'http://path.to/icon'
    }, {button:true} );
</script>
```