# Using ShareThis to share URL with Hash

Tags: javascript, hash, sharethis

How do I share a URL using sharethis which contains hash data.

For example:

```
http://sitesample.com/#hashdatafrommyapp,3
```

Right now when I use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x = false;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    stLight.options({
        publisher: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        doNotHash: true,
        doNotCopy: true,
        hashAddressBar: false,
        shorten:false,
        url: encodeURIComponent(document.location.href)
    });</script>
```

I get the URL without the hash (for example, when I share using Twitter button).

I also tried with `encodeURI()` function and it does the same.

Comment: Did you check 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835621/can-i-use-a-sharethis-addthis-button-if-my-sites-navigation-relies-on-hash-tags

Comment: that's for addthis, not sharethis, and I did try to change it like that and it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: Idan, any luck with this one?